# Qt + firebird подключение

Tags: c++, sql, база-данных, windows, qt

Товарищи, добрый вечер

Сбилдил два драйвера qsqlibase (32 и 64 битные версии) для 32 и 64 битных компиляторов кьюта соответственно

Когда пррописываю следующий код:

```
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{

    qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::isDriverAvailable("QIBASE");

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QIBASE");

    db.setUserName("SYSDBA");
    db.setPassword("masterkey");
   // db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("D:/Android/test.fdb");
    if (db.open())
        qDebug("The database connection is open.");


    qDebug() << db.lastError().text();

    return 1;
}
```

Результат всегда один и тот же:

```
true
"Install incomplete, please read the Compatibility chapter in the release notes for this version Error opening database"
```

Драйвер работает, но к базе не коннектится...Я уже не знаю что делать, всё перегуглил..совместимость проверял, сейчас юзаю полностью 32 битную птицу и 32 битный компилятор, в службах бёрд запущен, через IBExpert связь с БД есть, там всё норм...

Comment: А какой магией удалось IBExpert заставить подключаться?

Comment: @gbg, указал явно путь к 32-битному fbclient.dll в папке с 32-х битным файрбёрдом

Comment: А какая версия FB? Не знаю как в новых, но в старых версиях пароль не может быть длиннее 8 символов, точнее на уровне БД игнорируются 9 и последующие символы пароля, т.е. `masterkey` == `masterkevin`

Comment: Поставить в настройках запуска переменную окружения QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS и посмотреть, реально ли грузится плагин FB. Я стотыщьлет назад все это собирал, оно точно работало.
С другой стороны, я давно использую IBPP для подключения к firebird

Comment: @gbg, я зашёл в Firebird ISQL Tool и прописал команду 

CONNECT localhost:employee user SYSDBA password masterkey; и в ответ получил

Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
Install incomplete, please read the Compatibility chapter in the release notes for this version

Так что здесь дело даже не в кьюте...

Comment: @PotroNik, 3.0.7